# Draw vertical line along the entire height of the canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, kotlin, drawing

I have the following code:

```
class Canvass(context: Context) : View(context) {

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {

        canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255)

        val width = width
        val height = height

        val paint = Paint()

        var offset = 50
        paint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)

        paint.setStrokeWidth(2f)

        for (i in 0..100) {
            canvas.drawLine(0f, 30f + offset, width.toFloat(), 30f + offset, paint)
            offset += 40

        }

        canvas.drawLine(150f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat() , paint)

    }
}
```

It produces the following:

[image: result 1]

but I want the ***skewed*** line in the result to be vertical.

when I change:

```
canvas.drawLine(150f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat() , paint)
```

to something like:

```
canvas.drawLine(150f, 0f, width.toFloat(), 16000F, paint)
```

it gets closer to vertical but still skewed:

[image: result 2]

Comment: The first and third arguments in the `drawLine()` call need to be the same; e.g., `canvas.drawLine(150f, 0f, 150f, height.toFloat(), paint)`. Those are the x-coordinates of the two points.

Comment: @MikeM. It works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
canvas.drawLine(150f, //Start at x == 150
        0f, // And y = 0
        width.toFloat(),// Continue to x = width 
        height.toFloat(), //And y = height

        paint) // Not relevant to the position
```

Your x values have to match for it to be vertical. X is the value that matches width. When you have an x value at 150 and one at width, it will end up like that.

Straight lines always have matching x **or** y coordinates, depending on the direction. So, for this to work, you need to change `width.toFloat()` to `150f` or some other value.

---

I also highly recommend you read up on coordinate systems. You can take a look at [this](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J4b_CustomGraphics.html). Although it covers Java code, it's still the same system on Android.

Comment: How do I change the color of that line only?

Comment: Use a different `paint`.